# JAX-WS RI does not stream data from client

Tags: web-services, soap, streaming, jax-ws, mtom

I have written a simple upload service with JAX-WS RI. Classes are generated with `DataHandler` type by XJC. At coding time `@MTOM` and `@StreamingAttachment` are added to the service implementation. Now when a client, a .NET client, sends the uploaded data with MTOM `multipart/related` and data is received but the data source in the data handler is `com.sun.istack.ByteArrayDataSource` and `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`. This means that the stream from the client is fully consumed into memory. With larger files, the memory explodes.

After a few googling researches I haven't found anything but some SO questions regarding SOAP handlers which I do not have. No success yet.

I started a debugging session and figured out that the data internally is contained in a `StreamingDataHandler` which is the recommended way but the `MtomCodec` [queries](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxws/blob/97a1082379bb682adb771002c4beaae3df5d36ff/jaxws-ri/rt/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/ws/encoding/MtomCodec.java#L625-L630) the length of the attachment and causes the underlying data object to [fully consume the input stream into memory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/com/sun/xml/internal/org/jvnet/staxex/Base64Data.java#220). End of story.

This seems pretty brain-dead to me because the entire optimization from MTOM is completely gone.

Does anyone know a solution to this? Otherwise the entire approach in JAX-WS RI seems to be useless, I have to resort to REST.

This might be a duplicate of [MTOM not working when using SOAPHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12002632/696632). The outcome is the same.

For what it's worth, I am on:

- Tomcat 6.0.41
- Java 7
- JAXB 2.2.11
- JAX-WS 2.2.10

Comment: I have a number of questions about 1) which libraries you're using, 2) your client and server environments, 3) the specific client and/or server errors you're getting.  But ... SUGGESTION: See if this link has any useful tips: [Optimizing Binary Data Transmission Using MTOM/XOP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm#WSADV130).  In particular, something like `@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true, memoryThreshold=40000L)` might be applicable.

Comment: @FoggyDay, 1) versions are stated in the question. 3) client windows, dev machine windows. 3) I get the famous `OutOfMemoryError`. I have read the Oracle article right after my discoveries and applied both annotation the the service implementation class. No change happened. I have added `@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true, memoryThreshold=100_000L)`. The uploded file has 10 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further debugging sessions and searches on the net, I have found several JIRA issues and blog posts that it is plain broken in JAX-WS RI. As soon as you have a handler, you're lost. This applies to outgoing but especially to incoming streams.

At the end, JAX-WS RI is **unusable** for file interaction. I have to evaluate Apache CXF at some point.